# Mobx cannot resolve observable property decorator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I want to create a mobx observable whose data type is `map`. This is how I'm decorating the map:

`@observable.map items: Map<number, Item> = new Map();`

When I do this, I'm getting this error message:

```
the return type of a property decorator function must be either 'void' or 'any'. 
unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
```

What could be causing the error?

Here's my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@lib/*": ["../../lib/src/*"], // relative to baseUrl
    },
    "lib": [ "dom" ],
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "types": [
    "babylonjs",
    "jest",
  ],
  "typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    {
      "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you post TS config please?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just posted the TS config.

Comment: Your config extends some other config, so it's not clear what is the end result here. Anyway, have you configured decorators as described here https://mobx.js.org/enabling-decorators.html#typescript?

Comment: Actually, the config was set up by another person. I probably need to let that person know about this. I thought this was straightforward to tackle. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used `observable.map` as an annotation/decorator, so please correct me here if the issue was due to decorator configs.

The following could be a good alternative though

```
@observable.ref items: ObservableMap<number, Item> = observable.map();
```

This way you can track re-assignments on items, but all the values inside the map will also be tracked.

Note: mobx exports the ObservableMap type/class.